# how many repositories needed in MVC web application using .NET and UnitOfWork

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, repository, unit-of-work

first some background info.
the project i'm working on contains 18 domain klasses divided in 5 packages.

When Making a MVC Web application using .NET framework, the repoitory pattern and a unit of work. How many repositories are needed?

- 1 for each class that needs to be stored (in Db)?
- 1 for each package of domain classes?
- Something else?
- Or doesn't it matter and should I pick the option that is the most maintainable?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Last option is the best. Though you'll get this question marked as "opinion based" pretty quickly and sent to the bottom of questions.

Comment: That's a shame. I just want to read the opinions and make my own opinion based on them. That's not how Stackoverflow works, huh.

Answer (score 0):

This is an opinion based question but if I was working on this project, I decided to write a repository for per aggregate.
What is aggregates ?

Martin Fowler says:

> Aggregate is a pattern in Domain-Driven Design. A DDD aggregate is a
>   cluster of domain objects that can be treated as a single unit. An
>   example may be an order and its line-items, these will be separate
>   objects, but it's useful to treat the order (together with its line
>   items) as a single aggregate.
>
> An aggregate will have one of its component objects be the aggregate
>   root. Any references from outside the aggregate should only go to the
>   aggregate root. The root can thus ensure the integrity of the
>   aggregate as a whole.
>
> Aggregates are the basic element of transfer of data storage - you
>   request to load or save whole aggregates. Transactions should not
>   cross aggregate boundaries.

[image: Aggregates]

Take a look at [Effective Aggregate Design by Vaughn Vernon](http://dddcommunity.org/wp-content/uploads/files/pdf_articles/Vernon_2011_1.pdf) for how to design aggregates and you can check other links in the [DDD Community website](http://dddcommunity.org/).